# Can't install node_modules npm install error

Tags: node.js, npm

This is the error that shows me after `npm install`. I cloned successfully from bitbucket and all i do is git fetch to bring the other branch but it bring me nothing so i did git checkout branchname (branch name is upload in bitbucket)

```
Error: Command failed: git config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit 
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:291:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:380:11)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:598:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  git+https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk.git#2.7.0 resetting remote /Users/francocoronel/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-github-com-mapsplugin-cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk-git-2-7-0-324aac43 because of error: { Error: Command failed: git config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit 
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:291:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:380:11)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:598:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git config --get remote.origin.url' }
npm WARN deprecated cordova-plugin-contacts@3.0.1: This plugin has been deprecated
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it running: `npm install -g npm`